# Using subfolders in lib in a dynamic Java web project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anybody knows how can I create sub folders under the WEB-INF/lib and make it visible for Eclipse?

I have a lot of jars what I should put under the lib and I want to separate them with sub folders (like WEB-INF/lib/spring/anyjars, WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernatefolders/anyjars). In Eclipse it automatically adds any jars to web app libraries which is under WEB-INF/lib, but it does not do the same with jars in subfolder.

Please help me to solve my "sorting" issue